# Selecting date from a calendar plugin using appium and Selenium

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-calendar

It's been a serious task selecting date from a date plugin. I hve written a piece of code that does it to a limit. I have attached here the screenshots that detail the process of selection.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

script:

```
    _driver.FindElement(By.Id("com.appzonegroup.dejavuandroid.zoneRevamp:id/date_picker_year")).Click();
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
                int ThisYear = Int32.Parse( _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(AuthConstant.DatePickerYearButton)).Text);
    String RegistrableYear = Convert.ToString(ThisYear - 25);
    IList<IWebElement> calcButton = _driver.FindElements(By.Id("com.appzonegroup.dejavuandroid.zoneRevamp:id/month_text_view"));
                for(int i=0; i<calcButton.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(calcButton[i].Text == RegistrableYear)
                    {
                        new AuthUtils(_driver).WaitPageLoadById(RegistrableYear);
                        calcButton[i].Click();
                    }
                }
```

This code doesn't go pass the second screenshot. It does not scroll to select the 1999 year. Please help.